# НЕ с причастием при зависимом слове наречия времени ("долго не настроенный")

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Очень долго не настроенный радиоприёмник лежал на нашем складе без дела.*

Правильно ли, что в этом предложении НЕ с причастием пишется раздельно?

Answer (score 4):

Здесь **долго** - не зависимое от причастия слово, оно относится к сказуемому (долго лежал), потому и слитно: нет противопоставления, нет зависимых слов.

*Очень долго (какой?) **ненастроенный** (т.е. нерабочий) радиоприёмник лежал на нашем складе без дела*

Comment: А если "Очень долго не освещаемая местность"

Comment: Оканчивается на -мый, общим правилам не подчиняется. Смотрим, что это - причастие или прилагательное. К прилагательным относятся слова, образованные от непереходных глаголов: невредимый, невысыхаемый, независимый  или от глаголов сов. вида: невыполнимый, неистощимый. Слова на -мый, образованные от перех. глаголов несов. вида, в зависимости от контекста могут быть и страдат. причастиями, и прилагательными. Причаст. - при наличии пояснительного слова в творит. пад. и отрицат. наречия. У нас  пояснит. слово не отрицат. наречие и не в творит.пад. - прилагат., пишется слитно.

Comment: Если б было "ничем не освещаемая" - было бы раздельно. Можно заменить синонимом - очень долго тёмная местность.

Answer (score 2):

Даже смысл с первого раза трудно уловить.

*Ненастроенный радиоприемник очень долго лежал на складе без дела.*

Правильно ведь? Поменяли порядок слов - и смысл стал прозрачен. Или у вас "долго (не)настроенный"? Но это бессмысленное сочетание, так по-русски не говорят.

А *ненастроенный* здесь пишется с НЕ слитно - отрицания нет.

Comment: Если даже "Очень долго" относится к слову "лежал", возможно ли употребить "не настоенный" раздельно, чтобы подчеркнуть отсутствие настроенности?

Comment: Ога. ***Долго не настраиваемый*** приёмник может потерять любимую волну и не поведает никому голосом Марины Королёвой, как это - "Говорим по-русски"!

Comment: Неужели "долго не настроенный" несомненно некорректная форма? Как по мне, в этом есть и некоторая художественность, и гладкость. Долго заманчивый, долго прелестный.

Comment: Несомненно некорректная. А вот художественность тут ни при чем. Хотите художественности - используйте, но это будут чисто ваши окказионализмы.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ отменяется.

Это предложение не нуждалось в редактировании, оно, скорее всего, было задумано именно в таком виде.

Вероятно, автор хотел узнать, как пишется НЕ с причастием, если рядом с ним расположено зависимое слово, отнесенное к глаголу.

Такой вот интересный вопрос.

Comment: "Неиспользуемый" - это и значит "без дела". Плеоназм, стало быть. Ведь не просят же менять слова.

Comment: Конечно, рассказал, перечитайте. И Людмила рассказала.

Comment: А в его фразе - относится именно к глаголу. И никакой формы на -мый в ней нет. Зачем фантазировать?

Comment: Извините, но я удалила все свои комментарии.

Comment: Не понял... Я чем-то нарушил идею автора? :/

Comment: Всё нормально,  по поводу редактирования это мое личное мнение.

Comment: Ну ладно... А вообще, я сделал **не** большими буквами, просто чтоб не кавычить маленькое слово. А то можно было прочитать: "не с причастием (а с чем-то ещё)".